# Array of object is much slower than array of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Ruby on Rails 3.2. I have the following method to iterate through associations to find if photos exist:

```
  # Method 1
  def trip_photos
    if (photos = trip_days.map(&:spots).flatten.map(&:photos).flatten.map)
      photos.each do |photo|
        photo.url(:picture_preview)
      end
    end
  end
  # >> ['picture_1.jpg', 'picture_2.jpg']

  # Method 1 view
  @object.trip_photos.each do |photo|
    photo
  end


  # Method 2
  def trip_photos
    if (photos = trip_days.map(&:spots).flatten.map(&:photos).flatten.map)
      photos.each do |photo|
        photo
      end
    end
  end
  # >> [photo_object_1, photo_object_2]

  # Method 2 view
  @object.trip_photos.each do |photo|
    photo.data.url(:picture_preview)
  end
```

1. `Method 1` takes 30ms to execute; `Method 2` takes 400ms to execute. Is there any reason why?
2. I would prefer `Method 2` because I can get more data from the `photo` instead of just URL, but it has performance issues. How can I solve this?

Comment: what does `trip_days.map(&:spots).flatten.map(&:photos)` return?

Comment: It is a recursive loop, that returns the same result (if available) as depicted `# >>`.

Comment: Can you try `Photo.includes( :spot => :trip_days ).where( :trip_days => { id: trip_days.pluck(:id) } )` in the method 1 ?

Comment: Method 1 does not call "data" .   Method 2 calls `photo.data.url` and not just `photo.url`  .  Could this be the difference?

Answer (score 0):

As MrYoshiji says, you can probably refactor your request to minimize loops on your data collection.

A way to improve your Method 1 && Method 2: you can avoid the last `map` and `each` call, just return collection as the Array given by `flatten`

```
# Method 2
def trip_photos
  if (photos = trip_days.map(&:spots).flatten.map(&:photos).flatten)
    photos
  end
end
# >> [photo_object_1, photo_object_2]
```